# Hwow can I solve the problem of displaying arrays in C

Tags: arrays, c

The steps for this code

1. scan the dimension of an array✅
2. fill in it (integers)✅
3. displaying it✅
4. separate the positive numbers and put them in an array "POS[]"
5. and put the negative numbers in another array "NEG[]"
6. Dispalying the array POS
7. Dispalying the array NEG

```c
        #include <stdio.h>
        
        int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
            int n,i;
            int T[n];
            int NEG[60], POS[60];
            int negindex =0, posindex =0;
            printf("Veuillez saisir la dimension du tableau (N<60): ");
            scanf("%d",&n);
            //Remplissage du tableau
            for (i =0;i<n;i++){
                printf("T[%d] = ",i);
                scanf("%d",&T[i]);
            }
            //affichage du tableau
            printf("T[%d] = ",n);
            for (i =0;i<n;i++){
                printf("%d  ",T[i]);
            }
            //Séparer les nombres (positif | negatif) 
            for (i =0;i<n;i++){
                if(T[i]>0){
                    POS[posindex]=T[i];
                    posindex++;
                }
                else if(T[i]<0){
                    NEG[negindex]=T[i];
                    negindex++;
                }
            } 
            
            printf("\n");
            printf("POS[%d] = ",posindex);
            for (i =0;i<posindex;i++){
                printf("%d  ",POS[i]);
            }
            
            printf("\nNEG[%d] = ",negindex);
            for (i =0;i<negindex;i++){
                printf("%d  ",NEG[i]);
            }
            
            
            return 0;
        }
```

**THE RESULT**:

[image: The problem is in displaying the array of positive and negative numbers as you in the image]

```
**THE RESULT (txt)**
Veuillez saisir la dimension du tableau (N<60): 7
T[0] = 12
T[1] = 23
T[2] = -14
T[3] = 3
T[4] = -45
T[5] = 33
T[6] = 78
T[7] = 12  23  -14  3  -45  33  78
POS[6] = 12  23  3  12  23  3
NEG[1] = -14
```

Comment: Does your compiler raise some warnings? About using variable `n` without defining its value? It should! What size do you expect to get for this array: `int T[n];`?

Comment: It may the problem from 5 and 4 also I will unchek it now

Comment: No , I there is no error

Comment: What compiler? If you use GCC, you can use `-Wall -Wextra` to increase warning level.

Comment: yes, you are right, the problem is from the variable n

Comment: I really appreciate your HELP. THANKS A LOT

Comment: Step 2 is not correct - fix that first. See @Gerhardh comment and work on getting that and step 3 to work correctly. Post another question if you get into problems with step 4

Comment: Put `int T[n];` _after_ `scanf("%d",&n);` to fix the UB

Comment: a couple of tips that will help you : always initialize all variables, always check return value from runtime functions if they return something e.g. scan returns 0 when if fails.

Comment: Given the responses, the problem is already solved and the question is waiting for removal.

Answer (score 1):

Mustapha, after declaring 'int n, I;' you have to scan the value of 'n' first, and then you can declare the array of size 'n'. Else you'll get segmentation fault. Your first 7 lines of code should look like this -

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int n,I;
    printf("Veuillez saisir la dimension du tableau (N<60): ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int T[n];
    int NEG[60], POS[60];
    int negindex =0, posindex =0;
```

After this change, it'll work just perfectly...

Comment: "you'll get segmentation fault". This may happen or not. It is undefined behavior.